# React-Select - How to get text value of form before OnChange occurs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

So I am working on a search bar for a website of mine, and I am having a bit of trouble with one of the components I'm using, **react-select**.  Below is some example code

```
const baseOptions = [
      { label: 'Users', options: 
      [
      ]
      },
      { label: 'Pages', options: 
      [
      ]
      },
      { label: 'Search Google Index', value: 'search_google_index', type: "google_index" },
      { label: 'Search Bing Index', value: 'search_bing_index', disabled: 'yes' },
    ]

  handleSearchChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption,
    }, () => {
    console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedOption);
    switch (this.state.selectedOption.type) {
      case "user":
      window.location = "/@" + this.state.selectedOption.label
        break;
      case "google_index":
      console.log("Searching google index");

            /*Here is where I need to catch the value of react-select*/

        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    });
  };
```

#### The issue

I am not sure how to fetch the value of what is typed into the box **before** the new value is selected.

#### The Goal

I am aiming to search google for the term typed into the field when a user selects "Search Google Index"

Comment: what "box"? in the issue section

Answer (score 12):

According to [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select), to get the value typed in, you can use `onInputChange` props as following:

```
  handleInputChange = (inputValue) => {
        //get the character entered by user here in inputValue
  };
```

In your component calling:

```
<Select
onInputChange={handleInputChange}

....

/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-vaughan-rd8xq)

**Update:**

Recommendation:

You should use react-select drop-down only to show the list of users not for search options. For search options you can have two buttons.

Comment: Yes this works, and I do include it in my code locally, however the OnChange event is where I am looking to find the typed value.

Say I type in "birds", and select "Search Google Index", then the value is now changed to "Search Google Index", where I need to retrieve "birds" to send along the way :)

Comment: I don't think this is the purpose of dropdown menu instead you can use simply a textbox to get the input from user and two button labeling Search Google Index and Search Bing Index.

Comment: Yes but then you can't really search through a list of users can you ;) Thanks for the help either way, I will keep looking and post back if I find any answers.

Comment: If you have a list to deal with then you need to use react-select for the list of users only not for search options. For searching, you need to have two buttons.